# What do the subscripts represent in a Euler-Lagrange equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, notation, differentiation

What do the subscripts $i$ and $j$ represent in the following Euler-Lagrange equation?
$$
(d/dx_i)(\partial L_d/\partial \psi_j,_i)-\partial L_d/\partial \psi_j =0
$$

Comment: Usually the commas mean something like $\psi_{j,i} = \partial \psi_j/\partial x_i$; you may also sometimes see semi-colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Lagrangian $L$ which is a function of $\psi$ and it's first derivatives where $\psi$ is a vector with $N$ components then we have $N$ Euler-Lagrange equations 
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi_j} - \frac{d}{dx^i}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi_{j,i}}\right) = 0$$
for $j=1,2,3,\ldots, n$. We have $\psi_{j,i} \equiv \frac{\partial \psi_j}{\partial x_i}$ and here $x_i$ represents the $i$'th coordinate so in a relativistic setting $x_1 = t$, $x_2 = x$, $x_3 = y$ and $x_4 = z$ (or in a different order dependent on the convention used).

In the equation above one is also using [Einsteins summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) where a repeated coordinate-index is meant to be summed over. So the last term is to be interpreted as: $\frac{d}{dx^i}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi_{j,i}}\right) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^4\frac{d}{dx^i}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi_{j,i}}\right)$.

Comment: It seems worth noting in this context that summation over $i$ is implied.

Comment: @Winther Thanks! So is j just an abstract index?

Comment: @AwkwardPanda Yes.